# sqlite error:undefined swmbol:pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: c, sqlite, linker, pthreads

I'm trying to learn sqlite c api and written some code to test multiple database connections to same db file. this files compiles with no error but when i run it i get:

```
./sq: symbol lookup error: ./sq: undefined symbol: pthread_mutex_lock, version GLIBC_2.2.5
```

here is the code:

```
#include "../sqlite3.h"

int main()
{
    sqlite3 **my_db;
    sqlite3 **my_db2;   
    sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt;
    sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt2;
    int res;
    double res2;
    int rc;
    char pzTail[100];
    sqlite3_open("../test.db", my_db); 
    sqlite3_open("../test.db", my_db2);


    sqlite3_prepare_v2(*my_db, "select * from tbl1 where one='goog';", 50, ppStmt, &pzTail);
    rc = sqlite3_step(*ppStmt);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {

    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to fetch data: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(my_db));
    sqlite3_close(my_db);

    return 1;
    }  

    res = sqlite3_column_int(*ppStmt, 1);
    printf("we have %d\n",res);
    sqlite3_step(*ppStmt);
    res = sqlite3_column_int(*ppStmt, 1);
    printf("we have %f\n",res);
    sqlite3_step(*ppStmt);
    res = sqlite3_column_int(*ppStmt, 1);
    printf("we have %d\n",res);
    sqlite3_finalize(*ppStmt);
    sqlite3_close(*my_db);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run code without second sqlite3_open statement everything is right but when i add it,the error mentioned above appears at runtime and gdb shows this:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: .../sqlite-amalgamation3130000/playground/sq 
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
dl-debug.c:74: No such file or directory.
(process 4636) exited with code 0177]
```

I compiled this code with a copy of sqlite_amalgamation source instead of systems installed sqlite library for some reason with this command:

```
gcc -g -I.. sqlite_c_api.c ../sqlite3.c -ldl -pthread -o sq
```

and i tried 'pthread_mutex_lock()' on some machine in some multi-threaded application before.
Where is/are my mistake(s)?

Comment: Probably a typo: put `-lpthread` instead of `-pthread` (missing `l`) into your `gcc` invocation command.

Comment: Issuing the command: `$ ldd sq` reveals any missing object? (as in, `not found`)?

Comment: I tested changing -pthread to -lpthread. same reuslt.

Comment: @threadp don't know what i must look for but this command prints instance of libraries used and there is no 'not found' or similar commands.

Comment: @mhk ok, I guess sqlite is using one pthreads library, and `sq` is using another (i.e. different) pthreads library. Can you link your `sq` with -lpthread_db instead of -pthread ?

Comment: @threadp compilation stops with: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread_db
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status...

Comment: @mhk Usually, a symbol lookup failure occurs when there's a library version mismatch (the library used to link the binary differs from the library used to load the binary). I'm assuming you've compiled the binary in the same system as you're trying to execute it, so this is a little bit odd. Have you more than one pthreads library installed on your system? Can you compare the libpthread.so.0 path from `ldd sq` and `ldd $(which sqlite3)`? Are they pointing to the same file? (anyway, since the `sq` binary is not being loaded by sqlite3, they're unrelated for sure, but we need to start somewhere)

Comment: @threadp i tested ldd output and they points to same .so file. i don't know where to look for error...

Comment: @mhk try to link your binary against the system libsqlite3 (as in, with -lsqlite3 flag). See if anything changes.

Comment: @threadp it stops with a segmentation fault after open() function backtraced to dl_lookup.c...

Comment: @mhk Have you linked with `-lsqlite3 -ldl -pthread` (all 3 of them?)

Comment: @threadp it is weird but changing **pointers to *pointers and adding &s and... solved the problem

Comment: @mhk It makes sense! These functions are expecting a pointer to be passed by reference and a double pointer was being used instead. That was causing undefined behaviour, so anything could happen. Sorry, but I never looked into the code itself to check if something was being corrupted. Anyway, thanks for the update and the answer for the question :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it. The error was because i used ** pointers when i replaced them with * pointers and changed the code accordingly everything seems to be right.